# Testflightapp, AIR iOS app upload error

Tags: air, testflight

I have a trouble at uploading a AIR iOS app, it always say:
"Invalid Profile: distribution build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to false."

### step 1:

I package the app with the adhoc provision file, failed.

### step 2:

I added something to xml file.

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>Entitlements</key>
            <dict>
                <key>get-task-allow</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
....
```

still failed.

Comment: See if this question has the same case with you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435697/testflight-rejecting-build-get-task-allow-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[


        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <!-- iPhone support -->
            <string>1</string> 
            <!-- iPad support -->
            <!--<string>2</string>-->
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>

    <Entitlements>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <false/>

        ]]>
    </Entitlements>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```