# TestFlight iOS App get-task-allow Issue

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an app in testflight for ios called MapItTrackIt. Everything has been working great.

I just updated to xcode 5.1. I built the app exactly the same way I always have. Same profile and ad-hoc cert.

This time when I try to upload my IPA file I get the 'Invalid Profile: developer build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to true.' error.

I didn't change anything at all with provisioning or what not. I just added some more functionality to the app and rev'ed the version.

What the heck do I do now? How do I fix this? My boss wants this deployed right now and I can't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TestFlight rejecting build "get-task-allow" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435697/testflight-rejecting-build-get-task-allow-error)

Comment: I just encountered this problem. Restarting xcode and archiving the app again fixed it (I suspect this has something to do with the way xcode was generating the the entitlements file, though I'm not sure what).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are several different issues that can cause this. Mine was similar to JosephH's, but not the same.

For me there was another provisioning profile that was valid, but from a different user. I have several apple accounts that I am a member of for development.

My build was using a different profile from another user account when it went to sign. This was even though I had told it which one to use in the settings.

I solved this by having to delete that other provisioning profile whenever I wanted to build this app for testflight. The provisioning profile would always come back if I did an update from the dev site for that other user account.

The final solution was that I happened to get a new mac for development and didn't install that other user account's profiles into this mac yet. Now everything builds fine without doing anything.

Answer (score 107):

Same exact issue for about 4 hours today - restarting Xcode seems to be the fix as depressing as that is.

Comment: Wow, this fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Found this after 1 hour.. victory in comparison.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me!! Hours wasted! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just restarting XCode didn't help, but a full machine restart did the trick for me.

Comment: Shocking. Fixed it for me as well. :-)

Comment: Fixed for me as well.. Wow Thanks!

Comment: Fixed for me as well.. Where would I go if there were no stackoverflow!

Comment: For a few days my macbook had been asking to be restarted to complete an update. I kept delaying it but when I faced this issue, simply restarting XCode didn't help. So I restarted the macbook and let the updates get installed (OSX and Safari update). Then fired up XCode, clean-build-archive and uploaded again to TestFlight. No problems this time. What a waste of time :-/

Comment: This fixed for me as well, any idea the actual cause of the issue? After multiple cleans, builds and tweaking provisioning profile settings I was amazed that restarting xCode ultimately fixed the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Fixed for me as well. Pathetic.

Comment: Messing around with the Code Signing Identity and then resetting it and the restarting XCode a couple of times fixed this. Apple just didn't get famous for their developer tools I guess...

Answer (score 9):

I had this and solved it.

Xcode was using a different provisioning profile from the one I had expected it to - it was signing the build with a distribution certificate, but had created a development provisioning profile.

It turned out that the distribution certificate was somehow invalid. I discovered this by setting the provisioning profile explicitly in the project, which then prompted xcode to give me an error to tell me there were problems.

A good place to start solving these issues is to look in the build log, at the codesign step - there will be a line line:

```
Using code signing identity "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXX" and provisioning profile "YYYYYY" (<..guid...>)
```

Check this line says the certificate and profile you expect, and that the signing identity and profile are both distribution ones.

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was that I had a custom .framework bundled with the app that was not code signed. Apparently this unsigned framework caused the problem.

When I code signed the framework with a distribution certificate the app uploaded without problems.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this bug by changing my `Code Signing Identity - Release` part to **Distribution** certificate

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different ways. None of them works for me.

I thought maybe it's a problem of testflight.

So I used crashlytics to distribute my adhoc build. I had no problems to upload it.

Then I tried to use Organizer to validate this archive to get more information, I got an 
error. I was told this archive contains unsupported i386 and x86_64 architectures.It turned out that I used a framework which contains i386 and x86_64 architectures. Then I recreated a new framework which contains device only architectures. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Same exact issue here with the new Xcode 6.3 beta, solved by deleting the `Project.entitlements` (along with the `Code Signing Entitlements` entry on the `Build Settings` of the target)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was trying to update a label in the launch screen to show app name, version and build through a custom ViewController. This proved impossible to too complex so I deleted the View Controller. BUT I left the outlets in the Launch Screen Storyboard.  I deleted these (Last icon in Utilities tab, a right arrow in circle) and all is love, peace and joy.