# TestFlight 'Invalid Profile' get-task-allow flag is always false

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6-beta7

I'm attempting to distribute my app via TestFlight but my get-task-allow flag is always false when I build for distribution. I'm building on Xcode 6 B7 and iOS 8 only, with one of those new embedded frameworks. I'm not sure this matters or not.

I've seen other questions similar, but I don't think this is a new issue as none of the solutions seem to work:

[TestFlight rejecting build "get-task-allow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435697/testflight-rejecting-build-get-task-allow-error)

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully submitted a swift app to the old TestFlight portal from Xcode 6 GM.

My application had an embedded framework that had the automatic flag set for the Code Sign Identity.

What I was missing is to use an Ad Hoc profile (for some reasons Xcode 6 doesn't let you create ipas signed with development certificates), but also select my production certificate to sign a dependant swift framework that will be embedded into the main bundle.

I didn't select a Provisioning Profile for the embedded framework, but I did have to choose the very same production certificate, otherwise you'll get the get-task-allow issue, not because of the main bundle, but caused by the embedded framework.